# Mongoose pre remove works but does not output Console.log

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, hook

In my delete route, I am calling `Product.findByIdAndRemove(id)` which will trigger the `productScheme.pre('remove')` hook. My code works fine except that `console.log` never actually outputs anything on my terminal and I know that it works because the Product document is removed from the Categories.products array.

My product schema

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  brandName: { type: String, required : true }, // e.g. Holden
  name: { type: String, required : true }, // e.g. Commodore
  categories: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Category', default: [] }]
})

productSchema.pre('remove', next => {
  console.log('PRODUCT PRE REMOVE') // <--- Never gets outputted. Why?
  // The update works
  Category.update(
      { products : { $in : this._id } }, 
      { $pull: { products: this._id } },
      { multi: true })
  .exec()
  next()
})
```

My category schema

```
const categorySchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, required : true }, // e.g. Cars
  products: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Product', default: [] }]
})
```

Would appreciate some insight on why this is happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Sorry ppl.

The `productScheme.pre('remove')` is never really triggered.

On the other hand, the products from my Categories model are updated automatically when I call `Product.findByIdAndRemove(id)` because the reference is set to `null` and this removes the deleted product from the list of Category.products.

Similar behaviour occurs on a non-list reference. If I only have a single category for a single product (not a list of products) in my product schema, the value will be set to `null` when the category is deleted.